# What type of discontinuity is this, and does $0/0$ gurantee a removable discontinuity?

Tags: limits

Consider $f(x) = \frac{5x}{x}$, it has a removable discontinuity at $x=0$, as the limit from both sides exists (and is equal to $5$). Also at $x=0$ we have a $0/0$ issue (which up until now I thought guranteed a removable discontinuity). However, now consider $g(x) = \frac{sin(x)}{sin^2(x)}$. It's clear that when $sin(x)$ is non-zero we have $g(x) = cosec(x)$, but what happens when $sin(x) = 0$? $g$ still approaches $\pm \infty$ at say $x=\pi$ (from either side), so this doesn't match the definition of a removable discontinuity (in that case both limits would be equal and be finite), even though we have the $\frac{0}{0}$ form, there is no removable discontinuity, what is happening here?

Comment: The $\frac00$ form doesn't ensure a discontinuity is removeable.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2}$ , which is equal to $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. We cannot add a point to make this function continous at $x=0$ , so this discontinuity is not removable.